# Does Blackberry SDK have emulator or simulator?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Ok, so Android and WP7 SDKs have emulators, while iPhone has simulator. I am aware of **differences** between emulators and simulators.

I can't find anywhere if Blackberry SDK has an emulator or a simulator! Some books use word "emulator", while other use "simulator".

Can anyone clear up this confusion of mine?! Is this tool at iPhone simulator's level or at Android/WP7 emulator's level?

PS. I've just seen that this portal uses the term "simulator", so this may have already answered my question. However, I'll post this question anyway for the future reference.

Comment: Why do you care whether it's called simulator or emulator? The only thing that is worth knowing is that is usable.

Comment: @MrVincenzo You're not right. Emulator is better than simulator. I need to know at what extent I can trust him. For example, on Android I can trust his emulator in a way that an app tested on emulator will perfectly work on a phone. Such case is not with iPhone's Simulator.

Comment: @sandalone you are right but there is always some chance your code will work fine on simulator or emulator but not on the real device. It happens in Android and in Blackberry too. I dont have idea about iPhone so i can't say abt that.

Comment: @BBdev you should try to see iPhone's simulator, and then you'll what is simulator and how emulators are superior than simulators.

Comment: @MrVincenzo I see you're a BB developer. Don't you know is your SDK has emulator or simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlackBerry JDE and Eclipse RIM API Plugin both have **simulators**

Also many BB simulators are available for download.

There's no such thing as a public official RIM emulator for BlackBerry.

Comment: Is it called a simulator or it's a simulator by definition? So it's more like iPhone's simulator then like Android's emulator?

Comment: It is simulator by its nature.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is a little difference between simulator and emulator.

**SIMULATOR**

A simulator is a software that duplicates some processor in almost all the possible ways.

**EMULATOR**

An emulator is a hardware which duplicates the features and functions of a real system, so that it can behave like the actual system.

- Basically a simulator tests the program on the development processor
  (the processor on which we are working), while an emulator is used on the target processor (the processor for which the program is being written).

see this one to know more about it

[wiki for emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator)

[wiki for simulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation)

**UPDATE**

Blackberry SDK provides simulator because its look like the handheld mobile phone . And having all the features a mobile has. I think this what you want.

Comment: I know this. This was not the question here. All I need to know if BB has an emulator or simulator. That's it

Comment: see the update section for your answer. i was forget at first attempt sorry :(